# Conditional CIDER breakpoint not working in recursive functions

Tags: debugging, clojure, cider

I'm using CIDER for Clojure programming. I've been playing around with the CIDER debugger lately. I wanted to use the conditional breakpoint facility with some simple recursive function, such as factorial, so I got the following:

```
(defn factorial [n]
  #dbg ^{:break/when (< n 3)}(if (zero? n)
    1
    (* n (factorial (dec n)))))
```

It works correctly when I directly supply an argument that meets the requirement upon first function call, but apparently it *does not* work upon recursive function calls. So if I run e.g. `(factorial 10)`, the execution never stops at the breakpoint. Is this a known limitation of the CIDER debugger, like some tricky way in which it instruments the code? More importantly, is there any way to make it work with recursive functions?